# add button programmatically in if statement

Tags: android, button, if-statement, textview, android-relativelayout

i am trying to add a textview and a button programmatically in a if statement (if name == ""), but when i try to do so i get an error.

```
  if(name == ""){

        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
        TextView txt1 = new TextView(MyActivity.this);
        txt1.setText("add");
        Button add = new Button(MyActivity.this);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, fourm.class));
            }
        });
        rl.addView(txt1);
        rl.addView(add);

    }
    else {

         }
```

error code

```
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at app.com.pickup.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:58)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Also, could you post more code?

Comment: User, do you understand that for us to help you, we need to see where the error is. And since you took a random snippet out and gave us the line number, we can't actual find this line?

Comment: Whats on `line 58 of MainActivity?`

Answer (score 1):

adding the button looks good- I think your problem is the if comparison - do not use == for comparing strings. use either equals or isEmpty in your case

Answer (score 0):

use this code for comparison

```
if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
{
  //code to add button
}
```

and check where you have initlialised name..may be you have written String name=null..change it with String name=""; as you are getting null pointer exception

Comment: try to change the initialisation and comparison